# Elementary is 5.1 installation

Tags: system-installation, release-hera

I’m installing latest elementary OS 5.1 from USB on Linux x230 mSata. I pulled windows drive out so it’s the mSata is the only drove in. I loaded up and it’s stuck on “a start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (27 min / no limit) [image: installation]!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed issue by using BalenaEtcher to create elementary OS live USB drive instead of Rufus (both windows version) and used a different flash drive